# Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, https, php-openssl

I have a CMS using encryption openssl. I use it for a long time and this method works very well for me.

The problem occurred during the building of the first page by making use of SSL certificate and https connection.

Encyption method code:

```
$crypt = array(
    'key' => 'zM6XJLg1wKWvvzhoWHM7',
    'method' => 'AES-256-CBC',
    'iv' => 'gantedos',
);


function eco_encrypt($string) {
    global $crypt;
    $output = false;

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $crypt['key']);

    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $crypt['iv']), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $crypt['method'], $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);

    return $output;
}


function eco_decrypt($string) {
    global $crypt;
    $output = false;
    $key = hash('sha256', $crypt['key']);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $crypt['iv']), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $crypt['method'], $key, 0, $iv);

    return $output;
}


function eco_encrypt_md5($string) {
    global $crypt;
    $output = false;

    $key = hash('sha256', $crypt['key']);

    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $crypt['iv']), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $crypt['method'], $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);

    return md5($output);
}
```

now when i connect by https:// i received error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() in ...`

I have no idea how to solve this problem, because I really want to keep this method of encryption.

Is this at all possible? Please, any suggestions, proposals or other cryptographic methods.

Comment: you are calling a function called `openssl_encrypt()` but there is no such a function.

Comment: I guess, you cant load the extention openssl, please check all your extentions using `phpinfo()`

Comment: yes, but without https is working fine. This happens only when using a secure https connection

Comment: Php says, You are calling a function in your encrypt/decrypt methods, and this function `openssl_encrypt ` is nowhere.

Comment: problem just with https. Files are the same on both http and https

Comment: just when using https connection, openssl_encrypt php function becomes unavailable

Comment: @VuralAcar It's [part](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) of the openssl extension in PHP.

Comment: try http://ganted.pl/eco this login page with http, and after with https

Comment: @Jarek PHP doesn't care about SSL. It's part of your web server configuration (Apache, nginx, or something else). Perhaps you're using two different PHP versions depending on the used protocol. One contains the openssl extension and the other does not.

Comment: w ill check PHp versions on both protocols now. Maybe you right. it's weird

Comment: Thanks @Artjom, you right mate. On http is 5.6.19, on https 5.2.17. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Artjom B!. 
The PHP version changed on https connection. 
On http is 5.6.19, on https 5.2.17

Comment: That's an incredibly old PHP version. You really should use the same PHP installation for both protocols and update it as well.

Comment: I just  set 5.6 as the default for all server accounts. I did not know that, using the https protocol may affect the version of PHP on this same account. Thanks again man!